# How to create vertically centered meeting borders on a div?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/F8AN4/

I want a border on each side of the div that is vertically centered and is pointing to the left/right sides of the screen. I've seen this done a lot, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it!

It would look like:

```
-----|DIV|------
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}   

div::after {
    border-right: 10px solid black; // not sure how to do this.
    content: "";
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;    
}

div::before {
    content: "";
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us an image of what display you need(Upload image to imgur and share its url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need two wrapping containers: an inner div that holds the content, and an outer div:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is simple — the outer div will need to have 100% width (so that the pseudo-element can stretch to the full width), while the inner div can have a width that you designate later.

```
.inner {
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.outer:before {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The CSS transform property is used to ensure that the pseudo-element is perfectly vertically centered — it matters when the horizontal line you want is thick.

If you want odd-numbered dimensions for the horizontal line, you can choose to specify the height of a single border, i.e. `border-top: 1px solid #000;`, or abandon the border property and set the height and background-color. It works either way :)

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/F8AN4/9/

[Edit]: Remove the bottom margin on outer div, it was not necessary for the code to work ;)

Comment: You just need to add the left/right borders to `.inner` and you are done.

Comment: @MarcAudet It will not work, because the left and right borders will span the full height of the element. As far as I understand OP's request, he wanted something with a closer resemblance to a line, not a full-height border.

Comment: What I meant was the OP wanted vertical borders in addition to the horizontal line.  I based my comment on the answer by ExtPro which seems to be what the OP wanted.

Comment: That seems to be what the OP wanted, you've got it!

Answer (score 3):

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tUGrf/1098/)

HTML

```
<div><span>TEXT</span></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    top: -.7em;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
    border-width:0 2px;
    border-color:black;
    border-style:solid;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for ... but is there a way that doesn't require extra mark up and hard coded lengths? The font size would be dynamic for the div.

Comment: You do need the extra mark-up to get any styling control over the text element (specifically, padding and background color).  You need the parent/outer div to generate and place the horizontal line and the child/inner div to contain and style the text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/F8AN4/3/

I guess there is a more beautiful way to do it maybe someone has a better idea :)

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="hrleft"></div>
    <div class="mid"></div>
</div>

div.hrleft {
    height: 45px;
    width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```